# Can't get JQuery scrolling element to work with Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a JQuery element that scrolls with the page on the right-hand side of the page.

I'm trying to add this to a new Wordpress site but the code conflicts with the existing JQuery and the plugins I have installed.

I have used "wp_enqueue_scripts" in my functions.php file with no luck.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
function wpb_adding_scripts() {

if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('my_amazing_script', get_site_url('custom-scrolling-button.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
}
}
```

Here's the "custom-scrolling-button.js" code

```
        $(function() {
        var offset = $("#enquire-button").offset();
        var topPadding = 15;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $("#enquire-button").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $("#enquire-button").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            };
        });
    });
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Error in console? Shouldn't WP redefines `$` once doc is parsed?

Comment: Is your script - "custom-scrolling-button.js" not working with default wordpress jQuery?

Comment: Why are you deregistering jquery, and then unnecessarily load it again via google? Wordpress has jquery included in it for a purpose...

Comment: I removed the 3 lines de-registering jQuery but still it doesn't work. I even replaced $ with jQuery in the js file.

As a last attempt I added the jQuery code to the parent theme "custom.js" file and it still doesn't work.  I've given up